# Why does knife node status always gives unavailable everytime?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am very new to chef, i want to experiment creating jobs and executing it from the server against client nodes. Server and nodes have following configurations -

The server node has chef -v=11.16.0-1, private-chef -v=11.2.1-1, opscode-push-jobs-erver -v= 1.1.1-1 installed. And i boostrapped 2 client nodes they have chef -v=11.16.2-1,  opscode-push-jobs-client:i386 -v=1.1.4-1 installed.

```
knife node list
```

This gives node1 and node2 as result. And chef is running on nodes. Now when i execute-

```
knife node status node1
```

The result is -node1 unavailable. Please help me in finding out the mistake. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: `knife node status` is not a command that comes with Chef. Do you mean `knife status`?

Comment: I mean knife node status NODENAME.

Comment: @coderanger linked to this I think http://docs.getchef.com/enterprise/push_jobs.html#node-status

Comment: @Shona the unavailable status sounds like the push-job client is not started on your nodes or that there's a firewall blocking ports 10000-10003

Answer (score 0):

To translate from the comments above, you haven't fully configured/deployed the Push Jobs premium service. I would recommend contacting Chef Software support for further assistance as the FOSS community doesn't yet have much experience with this product.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the running processes and found that opscode-push-jobs-client is not running.
Starting opscode-push-jobs-client solved my problem.

Start opscode-push-jobs-client by following command

```
cd /opt/opscode-push-jobs-client/bin
./pushy-client
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue.

How I solved it is:

- I tried to install push jobs client via cookbook using chef-client to my new node
- After the install succeeded, on my workstation, I ran `knife node status` command with which I was able to reach out to that node. Further, the node status status changed to available.